# How to retain window coordinates for current session - VC++

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I want to retain child window coordinates if user drags the window to some location and closes it, so that on relaunch it should open in the previous coordinates.

But for the first time launch it should open up in the center of parent window.

Can I make child window to hide instead of closing so that it will open up in the same location on relaunch

Comment: Child windows are always located in the same location, relative to their parent. Have a look at [Window Features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx) to help you get the terminology right.

Comment: Of course, you can move a child within its parent, and you may want to preserve that new position.

Comment: @VladFeinstein: If by *you* you mean the user, then no, that is not possible. And since the OP is asking about the user dragging a window, this cannot be a child window. (Unless they have code to implement that feature. If that were the case, however, they wouldn't be asking about something as basic as retaining a window's position across restarts.)

Comment: `Can I make child window to hide instead of closing [...]` Yes, if there's no need for you to create the window again you *could* hide it. [`CWnd::ShowWindow(SW_HIDE)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72szh9c7.aspx)

Comment: - Once the user has dragged the window, save the coordinates in some file or in the registry.
 - Before showing the window, lookup it's saved coordinates. If there are no saved coordinates, show the window in  the center.

Comment: @IInspectable - by "you" I meant anybody :) I've just created a Win32 app using Visual Studio Wizard, and added this ONE line to the `InitInstance()` function, just before it returns:      `HWND hWndChild = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, L"Child", WS_CHILD | WS_CAPTION |WS_THICKFRAME | WS_VISIBLE,
    10, 20, 30, 40, hWnd, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);`  *WHAT* exactly is not possible???

Comment: @VladFeinstein: What's not possible with that code is, that the user drags the child window to change its position relative to its parent. That requires code, one way or another. Retaining its position relative to its parent is one of the [Window Features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx) of a child window.

Comment: @IInspectable - that single line of code creates a child window, that you **CAN** move inside its parent. Although the child window moves with its parent when the parent moves, its position in the parent is **NOT** fixed.
I challenge you to try.

Answer (score 1):

There is infrastructure in MFC to handle most of this for you. Note that when you open and close a wizard-generated window, it will already save state like window size and location, MRU etc.

Go to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983877.aspx and Ctrl-F for 'state'. You will see several methods that can be overridden to save state in. Most likely you'll want to implement Save/LoadCustomState in your CWinAppEx-derived class. Look at the implementation of SaveState in CWinAppEx to see how you would go about storing your own settings in the registry.

Re: center window on startup, you should implement that at the end of either InitInstance() or CMainFrame's OnCreate(), depending on what exactly you want to do.